# Check Contact Number and Email is fake or not?

Tags: angular, angular7

Is there any way to find out number or mail entered by user is fake or not? 
Using angular7 anf firebase?

Comment: Maybe you can try and use a RegEx expression to check. However, this will only check if the email and phone number is in the right format not if it actually exists

Comment: Create a mechanism where you can verify that, e.g. Email verification and mobile number verification using OTP. Other than that there is no way to check fake or not!

Comment: Yes, i already did those functionality but i wanted to know if mail or contact number entered by user is fake or not

Comment: Then you can only make email validation that send email which contains validation link , for mobile send sms contains pin code to validate it. There is no way without this.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can only make email validation that send email which contains validation link , 
Then search `mailchimp` services for this to send emails. Generally services allows to limited numbers as free.

for mobile send sms contains pin code to validate it.Then search sms services for this.

You should solve this backend part not angular part for security issues.

There is no way without using sms and email services.

Answer (score 0):

On the frontend side you can just validate the format of email or number

But if you need to verify if it is fake or real you might need to enable `one time password` implementation on backend side